# On .joins getting: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have 4 models

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :route_user, optional: true, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :route_users
  has_many :routes, through: :route_users
  has_many :vehicles, through: :routes
end

class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :routes
end

class Route < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :route_users, inverse_of: :route, dependent: :destroy
end

class RouteUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :route, inverse_of: :route_users, optional: true
end
```

I need to pull the vehicle's last `driver` (or `user`). The biggest problem here is that there are each vehicle has a lot of routes, which makes it expensive on the performance side to do something like: `vehicle.routes.last.route_users.last.user`;

The other suggested solution is to go from the other side, through the `user` model, and it seems like a logical solution for this problem:

```rb
  User.joins(routes: :vehicle).where(vehicle: {id:vehicle.id}).order('routes.created_at').last
```

However, I am getting the following error: `No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`

Full trace:

```
pry(main)> User.joins(routes: :vehicle).where(vehicles: {id: vehicle.id}).order('routes.created_at').last
  User Load (11.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "route_users" ON "route_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "routes" ON "routes"."id" = "route_users"."route_id" INNER JOIN "vehicles" ON "vehicles"."id" = "routes"."vehicle_id" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "vehicles"."id" = $1 ORDER BY routes.created_at DESC LIMIT $2  [["id", "b5b8f272-cfaa-11ec-8386-532e89b92b59"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = uuid
LINE 1: ...NER JOIN "route_users" ON "route_users"."user_id" = "users"....
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "route_users" ON "route_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "routes" ON "routes"."id" = "route_users"."route_id" INNER JOIN "vehicles" ON "vehicles"."id" = "routes"."vehicle_id" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "vehicles"."id" = $1 ORDER BY routes.created_at DESC LIMIT $2
```

How do I solve this issue? Am I even on the right path?

Comment: You are using UUIDs as the ID columns which is fine but I think the foreign key columns are using varchar. Look into the data types for "route_users"."user_id", "route_users"."route_id", and "routes"."vehicle_id" and make sure they are UUID columns as well.

Comment: I think you are right; my problem is that I am not too sure where to look and how to fix it

Comment: @engineersmnky does it mean that I need to write a custom query? I assume that it's not possible to get the result in a rails way

Comment: Look at your schema.rb file or check directly in the database. Either way when you find the issue you need to change the column from varchar to UUID or you are going to have continual issues.

Comment: @engineersmnky some of them are regular `IDs`; thank you for help!

Comment: @engineersmnky weird, but custom query takes even longer: `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN route_users ON route_users.user_id = CAST(users.id AS VARCHAR) INNER JOIN routes ON routes.id = CAST(route_users.route_id AS UUID) INNER JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.id = CAST(routes.vehicle_id AS UUID) where users.deleted_at IS NULL AND vehicles.id = '#{vehicle.id}' ORDER BY routes.created_at DESC LIMIT 1`; Thank you for the help again, you are 100% right